# How to update elements on display after passed time?

Tags: python, list, pygame, display

I got a program in Pygame which allows me to show up elements from the list `list`. Each 3 seconds, it updates and displays the next element from `list`.
My problem is that elements are overlapping on screen, but I want to update it each time 3 seconds have passed. I already used:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

but it does not work.

```
list = ["x", "y", "z"]
if time > 3 and i < len(list):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72)
    text2 = font.render(str(list[i]), True, (0, 128, 0))

    screen.blit(text2,
                (430 - text2.get_width() // 1, 220 - text2.get_height() // 2))

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that updates what's displayed every three seconds:

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

my_list = ["x", "y", "z"]
bkgr = BLACK
i = len(my_list) - 1  # Index of last elememnt (so first is next displayed).
start_time = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if (time.time() - start_time) > 3:  # 3 seconds since last update?
        i = (i + 1) % len(my_list)
        start_time = time.time()

        screen.fill(bkgr)
        text2 = font.render(str(my_list[i]), True, (0, 128, 0))
        screen.blit(text2, (430 - text2.get_width() // 1,
                            220 - text2.get_height() // 2))
        pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Thanks. Which line of code updates the screen? Is it {pygame.display.update()}? I used it in my first code also but nothing happened.

Comment: Yes, `pygame.display.update()` is the line that updates the display. Sorry, I'm not really sure what's wrong with your code, there's too much of stuff left out of it for me to determine the problem — it could be any one of many different things.

Comment: Thanks martineau. I would like to open another question, kind of similiar. maybe you could help also.

Comment: One more question: clock.tick() is always needed if you wanna update the screen, right?

Comment: It's not strictly needed — especially in this time-delayed updates example — although the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) do say it "should be called once per frame".

Comment: The question I got is: Is it enough to use clock.tick at the end of the whole code? Or do I need to call it each update I do?